# VBScript (HTA) MapNetworkDrive - Logon Failure

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am trying to create a HTA file that, among other things, connects to a remote network drive on a Windows 7 PC. In order to do this I need a username / password. I have the following code:

```
Sub ConnectDrive
        Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "x:", "\\testsystem3\temp", False, User, Pass
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            oShell.NameSpace("x:").Self.Name = "Temp on TS3"
        End If 
        Set oShell = Nothing
        Set objNetwork = Nothing
    End Sub
```

*User* and *Pass* are the actual username and password used in order to connect.

The problem is that I get a Logon failure error message: "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password".

I am sure that the username and password are ok since using the `net use x: \\testsystem3\temp /user:User pass` command connects the drive successfully.

Any suggestions how to get this to work? I could turn off password protected sharing on the Windows 7 machine but I wouldn't like that...

Thank you!

Comment: Does the username have the form `DOMAIN\USER` or `MACHINE\USER`?

Comment: the username doesn't include the DOMAIN or the MACHINE. Is that necessary? As I said, while using NET USE it works without that.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, but sometimes it helps. Why don't you try it?

Comment: i tried with `objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "x:", "\\testsystem3\temp", False, "testsystem3\User", Pass` and i still get the error...

Comment: What does the security eventlog on the server say about the failed logons?